# jquery validator regex using array or variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using jquery validator plugin with regex to test match input fields that only accept numbers and decimals from eg: 1.0 to 1.984375(1/64 increments) and it works but the regex is long and I need to reuse it multiple times but with some slight changes to the numbers preceding the decimal point.

I was wondering if there's a way to use an array for the decimal part of the regex, something like this...

```
var decimals = (\.015625|\.03125|\.046875...)?$
```

or

```
var decimals = (\.015625, \.03125, \.046875...)
```

and then in validator have something like...

```
regex=/^4+decimal+/
```

Is something like that possible?

EDIT: I added fractions to plalx code with fraction.js, which can be found here... http://hypervolu.me/~erik/fraction.js/.

```
var fractionsAll=range(1/64, 63/64, 1/64).map(convertToFraction).join('|');

function convertToFraction(num){
    return new Fraction(num)
};
```

example: 1-10

```
regexp: new RegExp('^([1-9]|10$)(\\.('+decimalsAll+')|\\s('+fractionsAll+'))?$')
```

Comment: Have a look at the `RegExp` constructor for dynamic expressions. However, there are better solutions that regular expressions to deal with that mathematical problem.

Comment: Not sure that it is possible, but you can use inArray() function

Comment: What about `function isOne64Increment(num) {
    return !(num % (1/64));
}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? The `RegExp` constructor allows to construct dynamic regular expressions from a string.

```
var decimals = range(.015625, 0.984375, 1/64).map(removeDotAndBefore).join('|');

var regex = new RegExp('^4(\\.(' + decimals + '))?$');


function range(from, to, increment) {
    var values = [];

    for (; from <= to; from += increment) values.push(from);

    return values;
}

function removeDotAndBefore(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/^\d+\./, '');
}
```

Note that you should be able to use the modulo operator to know if a number is dividable by 1/64.

```
function isOne64Increment(num) { return !(num % (1/64)); }

range(.015625, 0.984375, 1/64).every(isOne64Increment); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.inArray()

or function like that

```
<script>

var LOW_VALUE = 0.00001;

function check(number) {
    if (number < 1 || number > 1.99) return false
    return (Math.abs(number % (1/64)) < LOW_VALUE);
}

console.log(check(0.15625));
console.log(check(1.984375));
console.log(check(0.6));

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor like

```
//need to store the values as strings not as numerical values because otherwise the `0` prefix will come when it is converted to a string, also need to escape the `.` with 2 `\\`
var decimals = ['\\.015625', '\\.03125', '\\.046875'].join('|');

var regex= new RegExp('^4(' + decimals + ')$');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new RegExp` to construct a regexp from a string, and use `join` to construct a string from an array.

```
var decimals = ['.015625', '.03125', '.046875', ...];
var regex = new RegExp('^4(' + decimals.join('|').replace(/\./g, '\\.') + ')$');
```

The elements of `decimals` need to be strings. If they're numbers, then converting them to strings will add a leading `0` if the number is a fraction, and that will mess up the regexp. If you don't want to do that, you could use `Array.prototype.map` to call a function on each number that converts it to a string and removes the leading zero.